# Mongodb query all records inheriting parent `_id` down the stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following data structure in a collection with `N` entries inheriting passing down _id as `parent_id`.

Quiz: If i have top _id `"_id" : "56ce2713"` how can i query all down parent_id of parent_id of parent_id infinite.

```
{
    "_id" : "56ce2713",
    "name" : "one",
    "parent_id":null
    "insertedAt" : ISODate("2021-05-04T12:48:38.067Z"),
 }

{
    "_id" : "d0e6054e9795",
    "name" : "Two",
    "parent_id": "56ce2713"
    "insertedAt" : ISODate("2021-05-04T12:48:38.067Z"),
 }
 ...............
{
    "_id" : "6169-44a2",
    "name" : "N",
    "parent_id": "d0e6054e9795"
    "insertedAt" : ISODate("2021-05-04T12:48:38.067Z"),
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/), Performs a recursive search on a collection, with options for restricting the search by recursion depth and query filter,

- `$match` you conditions
- `$graphLookup` pass `_id` as `startWith` and `connectFromFields`, pass `parent_id` as `connectToField`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: "56ce2713" } },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$_id",
      connectFromField: "_id",
      connectToField: "parent_id",
      as: "children"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RNjt6AUB65y)